# LINQ Union Allways returning empty sets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm doing some LINQ to look for keywords typed in a textbox. Each keyword ends with ";" and i need to look for itens that contain at least one of those keys.

I thought that i would be able to achieve this with this loop

```
IEnumerable<ItemFAQ> allResults = null;
                    foreach (var item in termosPesquisaIsolados)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<ItemFAQ> tempResults = 
                                _dbHelpDesk.ItemFAQ
                                    .Where(x => x.DescricaoResposta.Contains(item) || x.TituloTopico.Contains(item))
                                    .ToList()
                                    .Select(x => new ItemFAQ
                                    {
                                        IdPergunta = x.IdPergunta,
                                        TituloTopico = x.TituloTopico,
                                        DescricaoResposta = x.DescricaoResposta.Substring(0, 100)
                                    });

                        if (allResults != null)
                            allResults = allResults.Union(tempResults);
                        else
                            allResults = tempResults;
                    }
```

At first iteration tempResult returns in a test 3 elements then it passes then to allResult, everything ok with that.

The second iteration, tempResult returns 2 ocurrences... then according to code allResult should receive the Union of AllResult and the TempResults, but no matter what i do, when i use the Union clause the result in an Empty Set.

So 3 + 2 = 0 at the end after using Union.

Do you guys can see the mistake at this peace of code or know some issues that could lead to this error ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing this line:

```
allResults = allResults.Union(tempResults);
```

with:

```
allResults = allResults.Union(tempResults).ToList();
```

Comment: After adding .ToList() the Loop throws a null reference exception

Comment: I got it. Some of the columns on the result set were returing null. After dealing with that everything worked with ur sugestion. Thanks.